# R: calculate time difference between specific events

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following dataset:

```
df = data.frame(cbind(user_id = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2,4)),
                  complete_order = c(rep(c(1,0,0,1), 2)),
                  order_date = c('2015-01-28', '2015-01-31', '2015-02-08', '2015-02-23', '2015-01-25', '2015-01-28', '2015-02-06', '2015-02-21')))  

library(lubridate)
df$order_date = as_date(df$order_date)

user_id complete_order order_date
      1              1 2015-01-28
      1              0 2015-01-31
      1              0 2015-02-08
      1              1 2015-02-23
      2              1 2015-01-25
      2              0 2015-01-28
      2              0 2015-02-06
      2              1 2015-02-21
```

I'm trying to calculate the difference in days between only completed orders for each user. The desirable outcome would look like this:

```
user_id complete_order order_date complete_order_time_diff
<fctr>         <fctr>     <date>              <time>
   1              1    2015-01-28             NA days
   1              0    2015-01-31              3 days
   1              0    2015-02-08             11 days
   1              1    2015-02-23             26 days
   2              1    2015-01-25             NA days
   2              0    2015-01-28              3 days
   2              0    2015-02-06             12 days
   2              1    2015-02-21             27 days
```

when I try this solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
group_by(user_id) %>%
mutate(complete_order_time_diff = order_date[complete_order==1]-lag(order_date[complete_order==1))
```

it returns the error:

`Error: incompatible size (3), expecting 4 (the group size) or 1`

Any help with this will be great, thank you!

Comment: It seems that you could try applying a function like `ff = function(complete, date) date - date[c(NA, cummax(complete * seq_along(complete))[-length(complete)])]` by "user_id" where "complete_order" and "order_date" are passed as "complete" and "date", respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for the distance of each order from the last completed one. Having a binary vector, `x`, `c(NA, cummax(x * seq_along(x))[-length(x)])` gives the indices of the last "1" seen before each element. Then, subtracting each element of "order_date" from the "order_date" at that respective index gives the desired output. E.g.

```
set.seed(1453); x = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)
set.seed(1821); y = sample(5, 10, TRUE)
cbind(x, y, 
      last_x = c(NA, cummax(x * seq_along(x))[-length(x)]), 
      y_diff = y - y[c(NA, cummax(x * seq_along(x))[-length(x)])])
#      x y last_x y_diff
# [1,] 1 3     NA     NA
# [2,] 0 3      1      0
# [3,] 1 5      1      2
# [4,] 0 1      3     -4
# [5,] 0 3      3     -2
# [6,] 1 5      3      0
# [7,] 1 1      6     -4
# [8,] 0 3      7      2
# [9,] 0 4      7      3
#[10,] 1 5      7      4
```

On your data, first format `df` for convenience:

```
df$order_date = as.Date(df$order_date)
df$complete_order = df$complete_order == "1"  # lose the 'factor'
```

And, then, either apply the above approach after a `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(user_id) %>% 
   mutate(time_diff = order_date - 
order_date[c(NA, cummax(complete_order * seq_along(complete_order))[-length(complete_order)])])
```

, or, perhaps give a try on operations that avoid grouping (assuming ordered "user_id") after accounting for the indices where "user_id" changes:

```
# save variables to vectors and keep a "logical" of when "id" changes
id = df$user_id
id_change = c(TRUE, id[-1] != id[-length(id)])

compl = df$complete_order
dord = df$order_date

# accounting for changes in "id", locate last completed order
i = c(NA, cummax((compl | id_change) * seq_along(compl))[-length(compl)])
is.na(i) = id_change

dord - dord[i]
#Time differences in days
#[1] NA  3 11 26 NA  3 12 27
```

Comment: thanks, @alexis_laz, it's definitely heading in the right direction. However, when I test your solution - with all data pre-processing steps - I get NAs for cancelled orders (completed_order == 0), any idea how to get around it?

Comment: @KasiaKulma : You mean in the example "df" or your actual data? If the latter, could you provide/`dput` an example were it returns `NA`? Both the "dplyr" approach and the last one return `NA`?

Comment: hi, it turned out the grouping in my test set was wrong, after correcting it, the solution worked like a charm, thank you! Also, thanks for a clear explanation of how your solution works, very useful!

Comment: @KasiaKulma : Glad you've found it helpful. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to apply the same principle to cancelled orders but the results are inconsistent even though the position of the last cancelled order is calculated correctly. Do you mind having a chat about it on this [chat]( http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132689/r-calculate-time-difference-between-specific-events) ?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(user_id, complete_order) %>% 
   mutate(c1 = order_date - lag(order_date)) %>% 
   group_by(user_id) %>% mutate(c2 = order_date - lag(order_date)) %>% ungroup %>% 
   mutate(complete_order_time_diff = ifelse(complete_order==0, c2, c1)) %>% 
   select(-c(c1, c2))
```

## Update

for multiple cancelled orders

```
 df %>% mutate(c3=cumsum( complete_order != "0")) %>% group_by(user_id, complete_order) %>% 
  mutate(c1 = order_date - lag(order_date)) %>% 
  group_by(user_id) %>% mutate(c2 = order_date - lag(order_date)) %>% 
  mutate(c2=as.numeric(c2)) %>% group_by(user_id, c3) %>% 
  mutate(c2=cumsum(ifelse(complete_order==1, 0, c2))) %>% ungroup %>% 
  mutate(complete_order_time_diff = ifelse(complete_order==0, c2, c1)) %>% 
  select(-c(c1, c2, c3))
```

## logic

`c3` is an `id` every time there is an order (i.e. `complete_order not 0`) to increment by 1.

`c1` calculates the day difference bu `user_id` (but for non complete orders the result is wrong)

`c2` fixes this inconsistency of `c1` with respect to non complete orders.

hope this clears things.

I would suggest you work with combinations of `group_by()` and `mutate(cumsum())` to better understand the results of having more than one grouped variable.

Comment: thanks, dimitris, unfortunately this doesn't work for me: as suggested in the desired outcome, I need to calculate time differences for cancelled orders (completed_order == 0) as well

Comment: helas! tried this before posting here and this solution will also calculate time difference between completed orders and cancelled orders. If we define  `time_diff  = x - y`, then `x` can be any type of order but `y` has to be a completed order, always. Hope this makes sense now

Comment: looks very promising, let me test it on a more complex dataset before I accept the answer, thanks!

Comment: Also i think the second last line of your desired outcome should be `9 days` instead of `6 days` and the last `24` or else i am still missing something.

Comment: OK, I can see that your solution works in most cases but not when there are multiple cancelled orders in the row for one customer. I'll edit the sample data set so that it takes such a scenario into account. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132500/discussion-between-dimitris-ps-and-kasia-kulma).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a `filter` function in place of the subsetting with `order_date[complete_order == 1]` and make sure the `order_date` (and other variables) are the correct data types by adding `stringsAsFactors = F` to `data.frame()`):

```
df = data.frame(cbind(user_id = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2,4)),
                      complete_order = c(rep(c(1,1,0,1), 2)),
                      order_date = c('2015-01-28', '2015-01-31', '2015-02-08', '2015-02-23', '2015-01-25', '2015-01-28', '2015-02-06', '2015-02-21')),
                stringsAsFactors = F)  

df$order_date <- lubridate::ymd(df$order_date)

df %>% 
    group_by(user_id) %>% 
    filter(complete_order == 1) %>% 
    mutate(complete_order_time_diff = order_date - lag(order_date))
```

This returns the time until the next complete order (and `NA` if there is not one):

```
  user_id complete_order order_date complete_order_time_diff
    <chr>          <chr>     <date>                   <time>
1       1              1 2015-01-28                  NA days
2       1              1 2015-01-31                   3 days
3       1              1 2015-02-23                  23 days
4       2              1 2015-01-25                  NA days
5       2              1 2015-01-28                   3 days
6       2              1 2015-02-21                  24 days
```

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks, but I need to keep cancelled orders (completed_orders == 0) in the dataset and calculate time differences for them as well