# R: Calculate measurement time-points for separate samples

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have measured concentrations of N2O for different samples (Series) during 10 min intervals. Each sample was measured two times a day for 9 days. The N2O analyzer saved data (conc.) every second!

My data now looks like this:

```
                   DATE Series        V       A         TIME Concentration
1: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:00.746     0.3512232
2: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:01.382     0.3498687
3: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:02.124     0.3482681
4: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:03.216     0.3459306
5: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:04.009     0.3459124
6: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:04.326     0.3456660
```

I would like to analyze gas fluxes using the R HMR package. For this, I need to calculate measurement time-points in increasing order out of the  exact time (TIME) data points. 
The time should look like this (table taken from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HMR/HMR.pdf)

```
Series;V;A;Time;Concentration
k0a; 140.6250; 0.5625; 0; 13.98
k0a; 140.6250; 0.5625; 10; 14.65
k0a; 140.6250; 0.5625; 20; 15.15
k0a; 140.6250; 0.5625; 30; 15.85
```

How can I calculate this for each individual 10-minute measurement period for each pot? Basically it should list the increasing nr. of seconds as my machine measured conc. every second.

My idea is to group by "Series" and "DATE" and do a loop. Inspired by [R: calculate time difference between specific events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505895/r-calculate-time-difference-between-specific-events)
Something like:

```
library(dplyr)
df.HMR %>% group_by(DATE, Series) %>% 
  mutate(time_diff = ????)
```

I would be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag` may solve the problem.

```
df.HMR=read.table(text="No DATE Series V A TIME Concentration 
              1: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:00.746 0.3512232 
              2: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:01.382 0.3498687 
              3: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:02.124 0.3482681 
              4: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:03.216 0.3459306 
              5: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:04.009 0.3459124 
              6: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z O11 0.004022 0.02011 10:16:04.326 0.3456660",
                  header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df.HMR %>% group_by(DATE, Series) %>% 
  mutate(dt=as.POSIXct(df.HMR$TIME,format="%H:%M:%S"), time_diff = dt-lag(dt))
```

Comment: Thank you @ Bing Sun! Unfortunately I get this error message: Fehler in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column dt must be length 1676 (the group size) or one, not 379698. TIME is saved as "chr", this should be fine, no? I think the problem is that I have measured each pot twice a day so I cannot just group by Date and Series but I have to define that this should be done for each pot two times separately (the morning and afternoon session). What is the easiest to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could attribute the "Session" (measurements in morning or afternoon" in a new column and I use this for the grouping:

df.HMR %>% group_by(DATE, Series, Session) %>% 
  mutate(dt=as.POSIXct(TIME,format="%H:%M:%S", origin = lubridate::origin), time_diff = dt-lag(dt))

1) did I use the correct information for "origin =..."?
2) I still get an error message: Fehler in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `dt` must be length 838 (the group size) or one, not 379698 --> I don't really understand why because I grouped before? If anyone can help I would be so happy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a few more questions. Need more data to see where the problem is. Better to formulate a new question.