# R: calculate closing time for chamber N2O flux measurements

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I performed static N2O chamber measurements that I would like to analyse now using the "gasfluxes package" https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gasfluxes/gasfluxes.pdf.
I measured different samples (POTS) during 10 min intervals. Each sample was measured two times a day (SESSION: AM, PM) for 9 days. The N2O analyzer saved data (conc.) every second!

My data now looks like this:

```
                   DATE POT    SESSION  TIME             Concentration
1: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 AM        10:16:00.746     0.3512232
2: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 AM        10:16:01.382     0.3498687
3: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 AM        10:16:02.124     0.3482681
4: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 AM        10:16:03.216     0.3459306
5: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 AM        10:16:04.009     0.3459124
6: 2017-10-18T00:00:00Z    O11 AM        10:16:04.326     0.3456660
```

To use the package, I need to calculate closing times out of the exact time (TIME) data points. The time should look like this (table taken from the package pdf. see above)

```
 serie        V A      time         C
1: ID1 0.522625 1 0.0000000 0.3317823
2: ID1 0.522625 1 0.3333333 0.3304053
3: ID1 0.522625 1 0.6666667 0.3394311
4: ID1 0.522625 1 1.0000000 0.4469102
5: ID2 0.523625 1 0.0000000 0.4572708
```

How can I calculate this for each individual 10-minute measurement period for each pot? Basically it should list the increasing nr. of seconds as my machine measured conc. every second.

My idea is to group by "POT", "DATE" and "Session" which creates a unique identifier for one complete chamber measurement and do a loop.

I also learned that I should use "lubridate" as I'm working with times (https://data.library.virginia.edu/working-with-dates-and-time-in-r-using-the-lubridate-package/). I still don't know how to calculate Time durations now for my case? I think I need to write a loop?

Something like this but I always get error messages (my former question [R: Calculate measurement time-points for separate samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839735/r-calculate-measurement-time-points-for-separate-samples/52840639?noredirect=1#comment92633694_52840639))

```
df.HMR %>% group_by(DATE, Series, Session) %>% 
  mutate(dt=as.POSIXct(df.HMR$TIME,format="%H:%M:%S"), time_diff = dt-lag(dt))
Error message: Column dt must be length 838 (the group size) or one, not 379698
```

Anyone can help me or knows about an another approach?

Any help is very welcome.
Many thanks!

Comment: With data.table I'd do this: `DT[, time := {
  t <- as.POSIXct(TIME, format="%H:%M:%OS");
  as.numeric(difftime(t, t[1], units = "hour"))
}, by = .(DATE, POT, SESSION)]`. Sorry, I don't speak dplyr.

Comment: This code works @Roland. Many many thanks for your help!